# How to name something that has sub-categories

Tags: word-choice, terminology

So I have this database of my categories. And every category can have sub-categories, except for the prime-level ones. In my database I designate a row that is pointing to the category which will contain this category as its sub-category.

How do I call that? *Mother Category*? Maybe there is more "technical" word for that?

*P.S.
Sorry, English is not my native language so I don't know many words*.

Comment: Can anyone add tag technical to this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In conceptual modelling, where we study whole/part relationships, we would call that the *whole*.

A more technical name would be *root*.

Answer (score 2):

As you're talking about using a database, I assume you might be looking for what the common technical terms are.

Generally, you'd use parent/child to describe the relationship between a category and it's sub-categories. The term root may be used to specify the container of all categories that have no parent.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest "Master Category" or "Top Category".